# How is the hard drive name remembered?

Tags: hard-drive

When I rename a hard drive then use it on another computer, the other computer knows the HDD's new name.

How does that work? Is it stored normally in the HDD, or is the device itself telling its name to the operating system?

Comment: It’s called a volume label and it is stored on the drive itself.  Here is some reading of your interested. https://www.lifewire.com/volume-label-2626045

Comment: If this is an NTFS formatted drive, then you can find more technical information here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Metafiles

Comment: @JG7 may I suggest that you take a few minutes and rewrite your comments as an answer instead?